# What would be some reasons to add a post under a structural beam if its not need?

Tags: structural, load-bearing, beam, post

We're planning to remove partition walls that houses our through and through fireplace. We have had the structural engineer provide stamped document regarding the structure which they indicated is not load bearing and the walls as well as post can be removed.

They did indicate that we may experience some minor deflection due to the beam not going through its full deflection due to the post being installed inside the structure. Which may cause drywall cracking on the ceiling.

All that said why would a builder add an extra post if it wasn't needed? I've included a picture of the inside of the structure showing the single post. We have the green light and yet I'm curious why they would bother adding a post that wasn't needed. Is it so simple that it was used to help install the beam and just left in since it would be covered. Curious if anyone had any opinions.

[image: Structure showing extra beam]

The structural engineer said they don't know why they put it in but it isn't needed to support the load.

Comment: Why is a difficult question to answer in this situation. Just trust the engineer's findings and proceed.

Comment: Usually they like a single piece of wood(a 4x4) instead of two pieces for a real post.  Some people prefer to over build than under, or wanted something there for nailing/screwing.  Maybe was used to hold the beam up till finish building and just left.

Comment: If you are speaking of the 2x4s in the middle of the pic, those look like deadwood. They are there to give something to screw the drywall to.

Comment: It seems to me that "not needed" contradicts "some [minor] deflection"...

Comment: A picture showing the back side/how that beam is mounted might help.  It seems an odd place to use a post so close to the wall.  Would make a bit more sense closer to front of the picture, with some distance from the back wall.

Comment: That grain looks a little odd, and the widths looks a little fat compared to the neighboring framing. Are those LVLs? What does the connection at that CMU wall look like? Could the LVLs have been supported at the correct elevation by the post during construction, waiting on the CMU wall to be grouted, no shrink grout to get installed under the LVLs in a wall pocket, etc.? If they were more toward midspan, I could imagine them being used to camber the beam until floor sheathing was glued and screwed.